# Character Detect into android Application Realtime

Tags: android, android-edittext, android-softkeyboard

In my application I had struck .Required your help.

I have to detect which character is pressed during writing into the **EditText** Fields.

Means while writing if I pressed key "**a**" from keyboard; application move to next step.

like this way.
so, How Can I detect the character into Real time in Android?.

I don't know but onkeyUp and Textwatcher may helpfull to me or not?

The code display below I found from StackOverflow but didn't work for me.
code:

```
    EditText editText= (EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText2);
 editText.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
              @Override
              public void afterTextChanged(Editable e) {
                String textFromEditView = e.toString();
                validateText(textFromEditView);
              }

              @Override
              public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {
                s = "sat";
                return;
              }

              @Override
              public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
                //nothing needed here...
              }
            });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
edittext.setOnKeyListener(new OnKeyListener() {

        @Override
        public boolean onKey(View v , int keyCode , KeyEvent event) {

            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            if (keyCode == event.KEYCODE_A) {
                // Do what you want here
            }

            return false;
        }
    });
```